# Is it possible to create "parent" class' method that accepts "child" class object as a parameter?

Tags: c++

What I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
class Parent{
.....
....
public:
  Child* func();
};

Child* Parent::func()
{
  Child C[] = {.....,....,...};
  return C;
}

class Child : Parent{....};
```

Excuse my total disregard for <array here.

Comment: I don't think those excessive `.........` clarifies your question.

Comment: It seems like what you need is the forward declaration for the `Child`.

Comment: It's possible but it's not a great design.  What actual problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: its not important what is defined inside the array or inside classes, i just want to know wether i can declare Parent class method as "Child*", and have it return Child class object

Comment: @NathanOliver Child class is only a data holder, I want a method from Parent class that can create an array of Child objects and put different data in each Child object element of such array, and then return the whole array in main funct

Comment: @starter_dev -- What role does that `Child C[]` play in all of this?  Is [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0eab4704e26e82e9) what you are trying to do?  If not, take that example, add to it, and post what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: you should not return a pointer to local array anyway.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Child class only holds certain data, I want to create an array of Child objects that stuff various data in each Child object element, then return that whole array to main

Comment: @starter_dev -- Use `std::vector<Child>`, not `Child *`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie but how do i preinitialize vector, like i do with array 
`
int arr[] = {...,...,...};
`

Comment: Yes, but you have to define `class Child` before `Child *Parent::func()`. And `class Child;` (not the `{...}`) before `class Parent {...};`

Comment: @user253751 yes, that fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *forward-declare* `Child` before using it in the *declaration* of `func()`.  This only works for pointers and references.  You would then need to fully *define* what `Child` looks like before you can make `Child` instances in the *definition* of `func()`, and then you can return `Child*` pointers as needed.

Note that returning a pointer to a local variable will lead to *undefined behavior*, since the variable gets destroyed when the function exits, leaving the returned pointer *dangling*, pointing to now-invalid memory.  You should instead return a `std::vector` of `Child*` pointers, eg:

```
#include <vector>

class Child;

class Parent{
...
public:
  std::vector<Child*> func();
};

class Child : public Parent{ ... };
```

```
std::vector<Child*> Parent::func()
{
  std::vector<Child*> C;
  C.push_back(new Child(...));
  C.push_back(new Child(...));
  C.push_back(new Child(...));
  return C;
}
```

```
Parent p;

std::vector<Child*> vec = p.func();
// use vec as needed...

for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
    delete vec[i]; // destroy each Child when done using it
}
```

Or better, use smart pointers instead, let the compiler handle the cleanup for you:

```
#include <vector>

class Child;

class Parent{
...
public:
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Child>> func();
};

class Child : public Parent{ ... };
```

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Child>> Parent::func()
{
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Child>> C;
  C.push_back(std::make_unique<Child>(...));
  C.push_back(std::make_unique<Child>(...));
  C.push_back(std::make_unique<Child>(...));
  return C;
}
```

```
Parent p;
auto vec = p.func();
// use vec as needed...
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/60cmJZ)

Comment: Does Child have to be a pointer? can it be just like
std::vector<Child> Parent::func(){}?

Comment: "*Does Child have to be a pointer?*" If you want to use `Child` in the declaration of `Parent` before `Child` has been fully declared, then yes.  `std::vector<Child>` needs the full declaration of `Child`, whereas `Child*` does not.

Comment: so if i understand well, i need to use pointer if Parent was declared and defined above Child in the code itself?

Comment: You need to use a pointer if `Child` has not been fully declared yet at the point where the pointer is being used. Period.